# Remove old crons when redeplying to AWS beanstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Not an expert on AWS and trying to fool around with Cron jobs. For testing, I had a sample script send me emails every minute. Now, I want to change it to once every 10 minutes (*/10 * * * *) These are the container commands I tried and none of them seems to work.

I am using a config file and a txt file to define the crons.

Config file contents (with various ideas I read from online sources)

```
container_commands: 
  00_remove_old_cron_jobs0:
    command: "rm -fr /etc/cron.d/cron_job"

  01_remove_old_cron_jobs1:
    command: "sudo sed -i 's/empty stuff//g' /etc/cron.d/cron_job"

  02_remove_old_cron_jobs2:
    command: "crontab -r || exit 0"

  03_cron_job: 
    command: "cat .ebextensions/cron_job.txt > /etc/cron.d/cron_job && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cron_job"
    leader_only: true
```

cron_job.txt file contents.

```
# The newline at the end of this file is extremely important.  Cron won't run without it.
0 * * * * ec2-user /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/cron1.php > /dev/null
0 * * * * ec2-user /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/html/cron2.php > /dev/null
*/10 * * * * ec2-user /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/cronTestEmailer.php > /dev/null
```

The test emailer script keeps firing every minute instead of every 10 mins and I dont know how I can make sure cron updates are reflected correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with the follow ebextensions config file.

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
             #!/bin/bash
             date > /tmp/date
             # Your actual script content
             exit 0
commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

More Details about the config file below:

1. **files**: Creates a Cron job and a file with the name myscript.sh. If a file with the same name exists already, first it moves the old file .bak and creates the file with new contents.
2. **commands**: deletes the all .bak files

Comment: Hi, I know this is old but I have this same solution applied but suddenly the `remove_old_cron` command seemed to not work anymore. on `mycron` I have many cronjobs and I laso created the respective scripts. But Then I deleted one cronjob from `mycron` and deployed, but the cronjob is still running. Any idea? thank you.